# Symfony 2 Primary key is one to one relation with parent table

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, schema.yml

I have two entities: User and UserProfile. At user entity primary key is autoincrement and named intUserID. UserProfile entity have the same primary key (but not autoincrement) and associated with User entity. When i'm trying to insert all user data to this entities, doctrine throws an exception: **Entity of type Project\UsersBundle\Entity\UserProfile is missing an assigned ID for field 'intuserid'**

YML mapping for UserEntity:

```
Project\UsersBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: user
fields:
    intuserid:
        id: true
        type: integer
        unsigned: true
        nullable: false
        column: intUserID
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    varname:
        type: string
        length: 150
        fixed: false
        nullable: false
        column: varName
    varemail:
        type: string
        length: 150
        fixed: false
        nullable: false
        column: varEmail
    varpassword:
        type: string
        length: 40
        fixed: false
        nullable: false
        column: varPassword

oneToOne:
    profile:
        targetEntity: Project\UsersBundle\Entity\UserProfile
        cascade: ["all"]
        joinColumn:
            name: intuserid
            referencedColumnName: intUserID

lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

YML form UserProfile:

```
Project\UsersBundle\Entity\UserProfile:
type: entity
table: user_profile
fields:
    intuserid:
        id: true
        type: integer
        unsigned: true
        nullable: false
        column: intUserID
    varsurname:
        type: string
        length: 50
        fixed: false
        nullable: true
        column: varSurname
    varpatronymic:
        type: string
        length: 50
        fixed: false
        nullable: true
        column: varPatronymic

oneToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Project\UsersBundle\Entity\User
        inversedBy: profile
        joinColumn:
            name: intuserid
            referencedColumnName: intUserID

lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

CreateAction:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $user->setVarSalt(md5(microtime().$user->getVarEmail()));

        if ($user->getVarPassword())
        {
            $encoder  = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setVarPassword($password);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Successfully saved');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_edit', array('id' => $user->getIntUserID())));
    }

    return $this->render('ProjectUsersBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Form User

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('varname', 'text', array('label' => 'Название', 'required' => true))
        ->add('varemail', 'text', array('label' => 'E-mail', 'required' => true))
        ->add('varpassword', 'password', array('label' => 'Пароль'))
        ->add('isactive', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Активен'))
        ->add('ispublic', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Публичный профиль'))
        ->add('profile', new UsersProfileType())
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Сохранить'));
}
```

Form UserProfile

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('varsurname', 'text', array('label' => 'Фамилия'))
        ->add('varpatronymic', 'text', array('label' => 'Отчество'))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Сохранить'));
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what is happening here without your form, but it seems that you are not setting the intuserid field on your UserProfile. If this is unclear, maybe post your form so we can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the field `intuserid` twice in your `UserProfile` entity. Remove the first declaration:

```
# remove this part
oneToOne:
user:
    targetEntity: Project\UsersBundle\Entity\User
    inversedBy: profile
    joinColumn:
        name: intuserid
        referencedColumnName: intUserID
```

You also may need to remove the `UserProfile` before persisting `User`.

```
// set the UserProfile to null (assumes null default value to setUserProfile)
$profile = $user->getUserProfile();
$user->setUserProfile();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
$profile->setIntuserid($user->getIntuserid());
$em->persist($profile);
$em->flush();
```